# How to get images to span 100% of div on 3 column grid?

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the noob question.

I have a grid that is 1200px wide. I have a 3 columns that span the 1200px. I know the issue is the grid works and spans the 1200px, but the images don't match up. I would like them to go the full 1200px across. I tried aligning the image1 to left, image 3 to right and center image align center, but the looked like the only one that moved was the left one which left a larger space in the center so they weren't equally spaced.

I created my example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sn7ojvLt/

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/1200x50" alt="middle image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/380x230" alt="featured works">
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/380x230" alt="featured works">
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/380x230" alt="featured works">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sn7ojvLt/1/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to explicitly set the widths of your images. If you set them to `width: 100%`, they will fill the whole column without being distorted.

http://jsfiddle.net/sn7ojvLt/2/

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of what I want, but if I add a margin or padding they won't align any longer on the right side or left side. I'm trying to have like 10px padding but have the left image flush with the left side of grid, right image on right side of grid and the center image centered between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a table to do this instead of divs. To make a cell span more than one column, use the colspan attribute. See example below.

```
<table style='width:100%'>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>555 77 854</td>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is essentially that of a table, but that isn't really a modern way to do this. I would simplify your markup a little, then you have more options when it comes to layout - if you wanted to do a mobile version for example - plus it's just easier to read and understand.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="main">main image</div>
    <div class="feature">feature 1</div>
    <div class="feature">feature 2</div>
    <div class="feature">feature 3</div>
</div>
```

Then I would have the following CSS classes for your grid, main and feature divs. I've added in some colours just so you can see where the blocks sit on the page - you can ignore those really:

```
.grid {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 1250px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background: lightblue;
}
.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: orange;
}
.feature {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 230px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: magenta;
}
.feature:nth-child(3) { background: pink; }
```

In this example we have specified your container - this could be any size - 100% width of a page would tie you a flexible layout. The main image is 100% of that width and 50px high.

Then we have 3x feature divs. Each one is a third of the width of the container exactly, and 230px tall. I have used the float property to sit them adjacent to each other. If you float items however they drop out of the flow of the container, so your container wouldn't inherit the height of the feature boxes. To solve that you set the overflow attribute to auto. I've added the container padding merely to show you that the box is that size as you can see it's light blue background.

The nth-child CSS can be ignored - it's only there to change the background colour of the middle feature so you can see the boundaries clearly.

If you wanted to add some space to the feature boxes you could set the box-sizing property to 'border-box' - so then adding a border wouldn't increase the width of the boxes.